# Can a Web API ActionFilterAttribute have access to model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'd like to be able to do some permission checks in a web api ActionFilter, so I need to be able to pull out the object ID.  I can do this on a GET since I have access to RouteData, but is it possible to get access to the searlized viewModel object in an action filter for a PUT\POST?

```
 public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("actionContext");
        }

       //Get ID from searlized object and check permissions for a POST\PUT? 
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried the ActionArguments property?

Comment: filterContext.ActionParameters

Comment: In MVC5 filterContext.ActionParameters has become filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetParameters() (returns an array of System.Web.Mvc.ParameterDescriptor)

Comment: Why are you guys talking about `filterContext` when it clearly is not present in OP's code sample?

Answer (score 0):

You have access to the serialized model through this property:

`actionContext.Response.Content`

It may be some work to determine what to deserialize from that property though. The Web API documentation is pretty sparse right now but [here is the official docs.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.content.aspx) The `Response.Content` type is `HttpReponseMessage` so you should find more details for deserialization by searching for that.

Answer (score 0):

Let me follow [@André Scartezini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1687249/andr%C3%A9-scartezini)'s answer and add a sample code I wrote.

It is an ActionFilter to automatically log posted data to a Web API method. It's not the best solution to do the job but just a sample code to show how to access the model from inside an ActionFilter attribute.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;

namespace LazyDIinWebApi.Models
{
    public class LogPostDataAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override async Task OnActionExecutingAsync(
            HttpActionContext actionContext, 
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Collection<HttpParameterDescriptor> parameters
                = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetParameters();
            HttpParameterDescriptor parameter
                = parameters == null ? null : parameters.FirstOrDefault();

            if (parameter != null)
            {
                string parameterName = parameter.ParameterName;
                Type parameterType = parameter.ParameterType;

                object parameterValue = 
                    actionContext.ActionArguments == null && !actionContext.ActionArguments.Any() ? 
                        null : 
                        actionContext.ActionArguments.First().Value;

                string logMessage = 
                    string.Format("Parameter {0} (Type: {1}) with value of '{2}'"
                        , parameterName, parameterType.FullName, parameterValue ?? "/null/");

                // use any logging framework, async is better!
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write(logMessage);
            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how to use it:

```
    // POST: api/myapi
    [LogPostData]
    public void Post(MyEntity myEntity)
    {
         // Your code here
    }
```